# R dataframe rows to lists in Matrix

Tags: r

I have some data:
`xData, yData, zData` (each of these is a vector of length 149)

I want to make a matrix such that each `ij` position within the matrix holds: `{xdata_n, ydata_n, zdata_n}`

For example:

```
xData = c(1,2,3, ... )
yData = c(4,5,6, ...)
zData = c(7,8,9, ...)
```

Where `...` is more data
I would like my matrix M to be:

```
|{1, 4, 7}, {...}|
|{2, 5, 8}, {...]|
|{3, 6, 9}, {...}|
|{...}    , {...}|
```

I am using RStudio and am pretty new to this, so am not sure where to really start.

Comment: Do you want a `list` for each cell?

Comment: @akrun Yes please ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- transpose(list(xData, yData, zData))
m1 <- matrix(lst1, ncol=1)
m1
#    [,1]     
#[1,] Integer,3
#[2,] Integer,3
#[3,] Integer,3
m1[,1]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 4 7

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 5 8

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 6 9
```

#### data

```
xData <- 1:3
yData <- 4:6
zData <- 7:9
```